# Event Sourcing: concurrently creating conflicting events

Tags: concurrency, apache-kafka, event-sourcing

I am trying to implement an Event Sourcing system using Kafka and have run into the following issue. During a new user sign-up I want to check if the username the user provided is already taken. However, consider the case where 2 users are trying to sign-up at the same time providing the same username.

In my understanding of how ES works the controller that processes the sign-up request will check if the request is valid, it will then send a new event (e.g. `NewUser`) to Kafka, and finally that event will be picked up by another controller which will persist it in a materialized view (e.g. Postgres DB). The problem is that the validation of the request is done against the materialized view but the actual persistence to it happens later. So because the 2 requests are being processed in parallel (by different service instances) they might both pass the validation, resulting in 2 `NewUser` messages. However, when the second controller tries to persist those 2 `NewUser` messages in the database saving the second event will fail because of the violation of the uniqueness constraint for the username.

Any ideas on how to address this?

Thanks.

### **UPDATE:**

In particular, I would like to verify whether the following are accepted approaches to the problem:

1. use the username as the userId (restrictive)
2. send an event to a topic partitioned by username and when validation
   is done send an event to another topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial validation against the materialized view won't be enough in most scenarios where you have constraints. There can always be some relevant events haven't been materialized yet. There are two main [concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Concurrency_control_mechanisms) approaches to ensure that correct results are generated:

**1. Pessimistic approach**:
If you want to validate constraints *before* you publish an event, you need to lock relevant resources (entity, aggregate or data set). The locking means your services must not be able to publish events on these resources. After this point, to get the current state of your data:

- You can wait until all events published before locking are materialized.
- You can read current state from the database and apply events on it in a separate process.

**2. Optimistic approach**:
In this approach, you perform your validations after publishing events. To achieve this, you need to implement a feedback mechanism. The process which consumes events and performs validations should be able to publish validation results. You can perform the validations in-memory when possible. Otherwise, you can rely on your materialized data store.

Martin Kleppman talks about a two-step solution for exactly the same problem [here](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka) and in [his book](http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/stream-processing.csp). In this solution, there are two topics: "claims" and "registrations". First, you publish a claim to take the username, then try to write it to the database, and finally publish the result to the registrations topic. At conceptual level, it follows the same steps in the second approach you have mentioned. In validation step, it avoids implementing validation logic and keeping secondary indexes in memory by relying on the database.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The pessimistic approach seems very limiting so for me that's not an option. The difficulty I am having with the optimistic approach is that events are supposed to describe something that has happened. So in my example if the event associated with a new user account is sent a new account is considered to have been created (e.g. other services will update their states, etc.). So what will be the result of creating a validation error event?

Comment: Yes, according to the most widespread definition of event sourcing, events describe something that has happened. But there is one more thing. These systems are often described as _eventually_ _consistent_ systems. It means that the system can be in an inconsistent state at some point in time. In this kind of systems, the typical approach is writing _compensating_ _services_ to undo actions. In your example, if your system is eventually consistent, a compensating service can publish a cancellation/deletion event for the second account after the violation is detected.

Comment: Kleppman talks about an alternative solution for exactly the same problem [here](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka). In this solution, there are two topics: "claims" and "registrations".  First, you publish a claim to take the username, which means your event is not really what has happened. You try to write it to the database, and then you publish the result to the registrations topic. In contrast to the previous approach I've talked about, this one is immediately consistent.

Comment: Notice that it is immediately consistent because the mutation caused by the event is only a single atomic write.

If you really need immediate consistency between separate data stores, that's another story and where things start to get annoying.

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed through the book as well and this was mentioned in there as well. This is basically option b) in my response to the comment made by VoiceOfUnreason: "send an event to a topic partitioned by username and when validation is done send an event to another topic". So it's good to verify that Kleppman considers this to be a best practice. If you can update your answer to mention this I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: I have added the example to my answer. If you would like your statements be referenced, please update your question as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> During a new user sign-up I want to check if the username the user provided is already taken.

You may want to review Greg Young's essay on [Set Validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).

> In my understanding of how ES works the controller that processes the sign-up request will check if the request is valid, it will then send a new event (e.g. NewUser) to Kafka, and finally that event will be picked up by another controller which will persist it in a materialized view (e.g. Postgres DB).

That's a little bit different from the usual arrangement.  (You may also want to review Greg's talk on [polyglot data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME).)

Suppose we begin with two writers; that's fine, but if there is going to be a single point of truth, then you are going to need synchronization somewhere.

The usual arrangement is to use a form of optimistic concurrency; when processing a request, you reserve a copy of your original state, then you do your calculation, and finally you send the book of record a `replace(originalState,newState)'.

So at this point, we have two writes racing toward the book of record

```
replace(red,green)
replace(red,blue)
```

At the book of record, the writes are processed in series.

```
[...,replace(red,blue)...,replace(red,green)]
```

So when the book of record processes `replace(red,blue)`, it performs a check that yes, the state is currently red, and swaps in blue.  Later, when the book of record tries to process `replace(red,green)`, the book of record performs the check, which fails because the state is no longer red.

So one of the writes has succeeded, and the other fails; the latter can propagate the failure outwards, or retry, or..., precisely what depends on the specific mechanics in question.  A retry should mean, of course, reload the "original state", at which point the model would discover that some previous edit already claimed the username.

> Any ideas on how to address this?

Single writer per stream makes the rest of the problem pretty simple, by eliminating the ambiguity introduced by having multiple in memory copies of the model.

Multiple writers using a synchronous write to the durable store is probably the most common design.  It requires an event store that understands the idea of writing to a specific location in a stream -- aka "expected version".

You can perform an asynchronous write, and then start doing other work until you get an acknowledgement that the write succeeded (or not, or until you time out, or)....

There's no magic -- if you want uniqueness (or any other sort of invariant enforcement, for that matter), then everybody needs to agree on a single authority, and anybody else who wants to propose a change won't know if it has been accepted without getting word back from the authority, and needs to be prepared for a rejected proposal.

(Note: this shouldn't be a surprise -- if you were using a traditional design with current state stored in a RDBMS, then your authority would be a user table in the database, with a uniqueness constraint on the username column, and the race would be between the two insert statements trying to finish their transaction first....)

Comment: I understand that the way to deal with race conditions like this is to enforce some kind of synchronization. No magic about this for sure. My problem is how to achieve this specifically with Kafka. Because my topics are partitioned by userId, I can think of 2 options: 

a) use the username as the userId, 
b) send an event to a topic partitioned by username and when validation is done send an event to another topic. 

Both of these are not ideal (for different reasons) and do not address the problem of enforcing uniqueness for more than 1 invariant.